# Изменен пароль к админ панели

Tags: администрирование

Здравствуйте. Есть такая проблема. Хотел зайти в админскую панель своего сайта, а мне говорит, что "логин или пароль не верно". Захожу в PHPMyAdmin, там доступ к админской панели изменен так: логин стоит admin, а пароль: 6488ac60a2a7bc367f42b839f1649ab3:TeseL73UiujPrmIpBvXdQguBHR3aKe5B.Что это такое и как с ним бороться?

Comment: что за движок?

Comment: 6488ac60a2a7bc367f42b839f1649ab3, очевидно MD5, пароль не простой, на http://www.md5this.com/list.php?page=87180&key=1&author=ToXiC&country=Cyprus&city=Nicosia его ещё не посчитали

Answer (score 3):

У меня для вас плохие новости.
Беглый поиск в гугле по "6488ac60a2a7bc367f42b839f1649ab3" дал ссылку на форум, в котором сообщают, что указанный вами хеш формируется из "janganjadihacker" .
Проверьте, если так, то вас скорее всего действительно взломали.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно с ним бороться. Это `crypt` — необратимое хеширование строки. Это наоборот хорошо. Подробности можно узнать [в документации по этой функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.crypt.php).

Answer (score 0):

Почти для каждой CMS есть примеры\инструкции для сброса пароля на администратора при кодировке его в MD5.
1. [Пример с CMS Drupal](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/59081/)
2. [Пример для Joomla](http://joomlaportal.ru/faq/issues-and-solutions/131-kak-vosstanovit-parol-superadministratora)
И даже [заготовки готовых паролей в MD5](http://www.joomla-docs.ru/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0).

*P.S. Через запросы к БД многие вещи сделать можно, главное пароль на БД не потерять!*